# Get highest user role in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, roles

I'm using Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle. I need to get the highest role for a User.

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_MODERATOR:   ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_MODERATOR
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

If a user has the roles `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` and `ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR`, I need a method like `$user->getHighestRole()` that would return `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`. I need it to be done inside the User entity, because I'm building a Rest API, and I want to expose the `getHighestRole()` method as a field.
I don't want to have redundant information about roles in the `security.yml` and in the `AppBundle\Entity\User.php`. Can I have access to `security.role_hierarchy` in the entity ?

I'm not even sure there is a highest role, since a role can contain any other.
Do you have any lead I could follow ?

Answer (score 4):

You are the one who decide which is the "highest" role, so you can simply do something like that in your User entity :

```
public function getHighestRole()
{
    $rolesSortedByImportance = ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_MODERATOR', 'ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR', 'ROLE_USER'];
    foreach ($rolesSortedByImportance as $role)
    {
        if (in_array($role, $this->roles))
        {
            return $role;
        }
    }

    return false; // Unknown role?
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, I need to repeat the role hierarchy in the entity.

Comment: Yes you need, because if you want to do something more dynamic you need to inject the container inside your entity and it's a bit uggly.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the role_hierarchy from container like:

but as entity classes should stay POPO it´s not a good idea to container aware

```
  $container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles')
```

alternative you could read the yml file with

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$yaml = new Parser();

$arrayOfOptions = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/security.yml'));
```

Comment: Yes, injecting the container is a bad idea/practice. And I can't use a manager, as I said, I need to return the entity

Comment: check my update, maybe you could manually parse the option value without using the container

Comment: That would be a solution, yes, but I think i'll stick with redundant information for now. We'll while using it if it causes problems